# Transfer Learning with CNN layer trainable True - Accuracy not improving

Tags: deep-learning, keras, cnn, image-classification, transfer-learning

I am working on a image classification problem with 4 classes. And I am using Transfer Learning (Resnet50) to train the model. Below are the observation.

Pre-trained weights are from `imagenet` dataset. 
 And images used in this problem are different from `imagenet` dataset.

**1. Transfer Learning (Resnet50) with CNN layer trainable false** 
 
After training the model, model accuracy was around 95% (which seems to be fair).

**2. Transfer Learning (Resnet50) with CNN layer trainable true** 
 
Since the images are different from `imagenet` dataset I planned to train the CNN layers as well. However I am not seeing any improvement in the accuracy of the model. After training for 50 epochs it reached an accuracy of 60% which is quite poor considering I got a better accuracy in case 1.

Could you please help me to increase the accuracy of the model in case 2?

Kindly let me know if you need more details.

Updates: 
 
Class distribution as given below 
Class A : 15000 
Class B : 11000 
Class C : 15000 
Class D :  7000

Code snippet :

```
def build_finetune_model(base_model, dropout, fc_layers, num_classes):
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = True

    x = base_model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)

    for fc in fc_layers:
        print(fc)
        x = Dense(fc, activation='relu')(x)
        x = Dropout(dropout)(x)

    preditions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    finetune_model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = preditions)

    return finetune_model

base_model = ResNet50(weights = 'imagenet',
                       include_top = False,
                       input_shape = (HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3))

finetune_model = build_finetune_model(base_model,
                                      dropout = dropout,
                                      fc_layers = FC_LAYERS,
                                      num_classes = len(class_list))
```

Thank you,
DeepGuy

Comment: Have you tried to train it from scratch? What optimization algorithm are you using? How large is your image dataset and how are the images distributed?

Comment: I build the base model using ResNet50 imagenet weights. I am using Adam optimizer with learning rate = 0.001. Class distribution : 2 classes with 15000 images each, one with 11000 and one with 7000. I will also update my question with code snippet.